# Android orientation & DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-edittext

Добрый день!

Проблема: при открытом DialogFragment при смене ориентации вылетает исключение. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобным и есть ли методы решения?

Также интересует: как отследить изменения в EditText не через TextWatcher? (Требуется отловить лишь события набора текста, без события программного изменения.)

С уважением, Игорь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По поводу того, что вылетает exception при смене ориентации. Какое именно исключение? Покажите stacktrace. Попробуйте сделать следующее: добавьте `setRetainInstance(true)` в методе `onCreateDialog()`.

Насчет того как отловить изменения в EditText, есть несколько способов. Можно сделать класс адаптер, который будет просто оберткой (заглушкой) методов интерфейса TextWatcher, соответственно вы сможете просто переопределить нужный Вам метод.

Вообще вам нужно все равно будет использовать какой-то интерфейс слушателя. Возможен еще такой вариант с `OnFocusChangeListener`. Данный интерфейс имеет только один метод `onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)`, сюда передается булевая переменная, которая показывает, был ли измен фокус данного View.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я не могу сейчас, к сожалению, показать stacktrace, т.к. отобрали "испытуемого", еще раз большое спасибо.